# Writing a memory stream to a file

Tags: c#, json, memorystream

I have tried retrieving data in the json format as a string and writing it to a file and it worked great. Now I am trying to use MemoryStream to do the same thing but nothing gets written to a file - merely [{},{},{},{},{}] without any actual data.

My question is - how can I check if data indeed goes to memory stream correctly or if the problem occurs somewhere else. I do know that myList does contain data.

Here is my code:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer dcjs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<myClass>));
dcjs.WriteObject(ms, myList);

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"MyFile.json"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.Read(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
                fs.Write(ms.ToArray(), 0, ms.ToArray().Length);
                ms.Close();
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Not saying that this will fix your problem, but consider cleaning up the code by using [Stream.CopyTo Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `ms.Read(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);` Why are you reading the memory stream, overwriting whatever was put in there by `dcjs.WriteObject`? That seems like your problem there, don't reset the stream position and write over itself.

Comment: Why are you writing to the MemoryStream before the FileStream? But with .net 4.0 you should have access to `Stream.CopyTo(Stream)`.

Comment: I tried ms.CopyTo(fs) but gotten same result

Comment: @ElenaDBA The problem isn't your file writing. The problem is in your Serializer.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is a very handy method, `Stream.CopyTo(Stream)`.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ms);

    writer.WriteLine("asdasdasasdfasdasd");
    writer.Flush();

    //You have to rewind the MemoryStream before copying
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("output.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        ms.CopyTo(fs);
        fs.Flush();
    }
}
```

Also, you don't have to close `fs` since it's in a using statement and will be disposed at the end.

Comment: Nothing happened at all - the file was unchanged

Comment: I updated the code with a modification, you need to use Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

Comment: I'm using .Net Framework 3.5, so that may have something to do with it, but I could use `Stream.CopyTo(Stream)` as it did not exist. Instead, I had to use `Stream.WriteTo(Stream)`.

Comment: Instead of  ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) you can use ms.Position = 0 to "rewind" the stream

Comment: Strictly speaking, `fs.Flush()` is redundant, no? Because the filestream will Flush when it's `Close()`d by `Dispose()`? (I'm asking because I have a related bug, but I can't believe that adding `Flush()` in all places where I open a file stream will solve anything)

Answer (score 4):

```
 using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
    ...

     var fileName = $"FileName.xlsx";
     string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath() + fileName );
     using (var fs = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
     {
        memoryStream.WriteTo(fs);
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

//reset the position of the stream

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

//Then copy to filestream

```
ms.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

Comment: There is no reason to reset the stream position, just calling `ms.ToArray()` will copy the entire memory stream (beginning at zero) to an array. From the documentation *"Writes the stream contents to a byte array, **regardless of the Position property**."*

Answer (score 1):

The issue is nothing to do with your file stream/ memory stream. The problem is that `DataContractJsonSerializer` is an OPT IN Serializer. You need to add `[DataMemberAttribute]` to all the properties that you need to serialize on `myClass`.

```
[DataContract]
public class myClass
{
     [DataMember]
     public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks problematic:

```
ms.Read(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
```

You shouldn't need to read anything into the memory stream at this point, particularly when you're code is written to read ms into ms.

I'm pretty confident that simply removing this line will fix your problem.

Comment: Before I tried ms.WriteTo(fs) but result was the same